# Doing a top level navigation with drop downs: have IE bugs pt.2

Tags: css, internet-explorer-6

Sample code is below. If you look at it, you will see gray drop down boxes. These boxes are present in all browsers, but don't show in IE6 / IE7. Is there anyway to get this working in those browsers, without removing styles critical to the layout (for instance, I think removing a overflow: hidden off of something gets it to work but breaks the entire thing in IE6/IE7):

http://jsbin.com/ohufu4/edit

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">



  <title>Title</title>
    <style type="text/css">

/* RESET ------------------------------------- */
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, font, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0; }

body {
  font-size: 62.5%; }

/* END OF RESET ------------------------------ */
a img {
  border: none;
  display: none; }

h1 {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 19px;
  color: #333;
  margin-bottom: 20px; }

h2 {
  margin: 10px 0;
  font: bold 13px Verdana;
  color: #333; }

html, body {
  height: 100%; }

body {
  font-family: Verdana; }

#header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  padding: 15px 0;
  background: #FFFFFF; }

#header_nest {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 5%; }
  #header_nest img {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle; }
    body.ie6 #header_nest img, body.ie7 #header_nest img {
      display: inline; }
  #header_nest p {
    font: normal 10px Verdana;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 25px 0 15px; }
    body.ie6 #header_nest p, body.ie7 #header_nest p {
      display: inline; }

ul#nav {
  padding: 0 0 0 20px;
  position: relative; }
  ul#nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font: normal 11px Verdana, sans-serif;
    list-style-type: none;
    position: relative; }
    body.ie6 ul#nav li, body.ie7 ul#nav li {
      display: inline; }
    ul#nav li h2 {
      display: inline-block;
      vertical-align: middle;
      z-index: -1;
      margin: 0;
      font: normal 11px Verdana, sans-serif; }
      body.ie6 ul#nav li h2, body.ie7 ul#nav li h2 {
        display: inline; }
      ul#nav li h2 a {
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: middle;
        z-index: 4;
        text-decoration: none;
        position: relative;
        color: #999;
        padding: 20px 10px 20px 40px;
        white-space: nowrap; }
        body.ie6 ul#nav li h2 a, body.ie7 ul#nav li h2 a {
          display: inline; }
  ul#nav li.mega {
    z-index: 30; }
  ul#nav li.mega div {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 200;
    padding: 10px;
    border-left: 1px solid #999;
    border-right: 3px solid #999;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #999;
    top: 52px;
    left: 0;
    margin-right: 40px;
    background: #CCC;
    /* commenting out for test case: display: none;  */ }
    ul#nav li.mega div h3 {
      display: inline;
      font: bold 13px Verdana, sans-serif; }
  ul#nav li.hovering div {
    display: block; }
  ul#nav img {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -12px;
    left: 8px; }

#main {
  padding-right: 300px; }

#content {
  float: left;
  display: inline; }

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  /* Minimum width remove line if not required (does not work in IE) */ }

/* column container */
.colmask {
  position: relative;
  /* This fixes the IE7 overflow hidden bug and stops the layout jumping out of place */
  clear: both;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  /* width of whole page */
  overflow: hidden;
  /* This chops off any overhanging divs */ }

/* 2 column right menu settings */
.rightmenu {
  /* display: none; */ }

.rightmenu .colleft {
  float: left;
  width: 200%;
  margin-left: -200px;
  position: relative;
  right: 100%;
  background: #fff; }

.rightmenu .col1wrap {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  padding-bottom: 1em; }

.rightmenu .col1 {
  margin: 50px 55px 0 245px;
  /* removed temporarily: overflow:auto; */
  padding-bottom: 20px; }

.rightmenu .col2 {
  float: right;
  width: 180px;
  position: relative;
  left: 195px; }
  .rightmenu .col2 h3 {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #FFFFF;
    margin-left: -9px;
    padding: 10px 9px;
    background-color: #5D973A;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 100%;
    color: #EEEEEE; }
    body.ie6 .rightmenu .col2 h3, body.ie7 .rightmenu .col2 h3 {
      display: inline; }

#sidebar {
  width: 200px;
  color: black;
  float: right;
  display: inline;
  height: 300px; }

#footer {
  width: 100%;
  clear: both;
  background: #333; }
  #footer ul {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 30px; }
    body.ie6 #footer ul, body.ie7 #footer ul {
      display: inline; }
    #footer ul li {
      display: inline-block;
      list-style-type: none;
      margin: 0 9px; }
      body.ie6 #footer ul li, body.ie7 #footer ul li {
        display: inline; }
      #footer ul li a {
        color: #FFF;
        text-decoration: none;
        font: normal 1.4em Verdana, sans-serif; }

.dataset {
  display: none;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 100%;
  font: normal 13px Verdana, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin: 0 0 0 0; 
  height: 200px;
}

.dataTables_wrapper {
  margin: 0 0 40px 0; }

.dataset td {
  padding: 3px 10px; }

.dataset th {
  font: bold 10px Verdana, sans-serif;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 7px 3px 4px 10px; }

.dataTables_filter {
  margin: 8px;
  float: right; }

.dataTables_length {
  margin: 8px;
  float: left; }

.dataTables_info {
  margin: 8px;
  float: left; }

.dataTables_paginate {
  margin: 8px;
  float: right; }
  .dataTables_paginate .ui-state-default {
    padding: 2px; }

/* environmental impact styles */
#pg_environmental-impact .dataset tr.odd, #pg_reporting .dataset tr.odd {
  background-color: #DDFFDD; }
#pg_environmental-impact .dataset tr.odd td:first-child, #pg_reporting .dataset tr.odd td:first-child {
  background-color: #C4FFC4; }
#pg_environmental-impact .dataset tr.even td:first-child, #pg_reporting .dataset tr.even td:first-child {
  background-color: #D5FFD5; }

.grp_dash .dataTables_scrollBody {
  border-left: 1px solid #CCC;
  border-right: 1px solid #CCC;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC; }

/* end environmental impact styles */
/* Login Styles */
#pg_login {
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%; }
  #pg_login #login_nested {
    height: 200px;
    width: 298px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -100px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -150px;
    text-align: right;
    font: normal 12px Verdana, sans-serif; }
    #pg_login #login_nested img {
      text-align: right;
      margin: 19px 39px 0 0; }
    #pg_login #login_nested form {
      margin-top: -10px;
      text-align: left;
      padding: 0 39px 30px; }
    #pg_login #login_nested input#submit {
      display: inline-block;
      background-color: #808080;
      color: white;
      border: none;
      padding: 10px;
      font-size: 12px;
      width: 100%;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #666;
      border-left: 1px solid #777; }
      body.ie6 #pg_login #login_nested input#submit, body.ie7 #pg_login #login_nested input#submit {
        display: inline; }
    #pg_login #login_nested ul.errorlist {
      color: red;
      margin: 5px 0; }
      #pg_login #login_nested ul.errorlist li {
        list-style-type: none;
        font: normal 10px Verdana, sans-serif; }
    #pg_login #login_nested #id_username, #pg_login #login_nested #id_password, #pg_login #login_nested .placeholder {
      padding: 7px 6px;
      margin: 3px 0px;
      width: 206px;
      position: relative;
      display: block; }
    #pg_login #login_nested .placeholder {
      color: #999; }

.grp_dash .highlights {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 15px 10px 15px; }
  body.ie6 .grp_dash .highlights, body.ie7 .grp_dash .highlights {
    display: inline; }
  .grp_dash .highlights p {
    display: inline-block;
    font: normal 12px Verdana;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 25px 15px 0; }
    body.ie6 .grp_dash .highlights p, body.ie7 .grp_dash .highlights p {
      display: inline; }
    .grp_dash .highlights p strong {
      display: block;
      font: bold 14px Verdana; }

/* filterable pages */
#pg_reporting form fieldset, #pg_environmental-impact form fieldset {
  display: none;
  border: none; }
  #pg_reporting form fieldset ul li, #pg_environmental-impact form fieldset ul li {
    list-style-type: none; }
    #pg_reporting form fieldset ul li label, #pg_environmental-impact form fieldset ul li label {
      display: inline; }

form label {
  /* display: block; */ }

/* export module */
#export_module {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  margin-top: -10px;
  display: none; }


</style>

</head>


<!--[if lte IE 6]><body class="ie6 ie7"><![endif]-->

<!--[if lte IE 7]><body class="ie7"><![endif]-->
<!--[if gte IE 8]><!--><body><!--<![endif]-->
<div id="pg_environmental-impact" class="">
  <div id="header">
    <div id="header_nest">

      <p>Hello, <strong>User</strong><br /> 

<a href="/help/contact/">Get Help</a> |


  <a href="/logout/">Logout</a></p>

      </div>
  </div>
  <ul id="nav">


<li class="mega">
  <h2><a href="/">Blah</a></h2></li>


    <li class="mega" style="z-index: 40;">
        <h2><a href="#">Environmental Impact</a></h2>

        <div>
            <h3>Blah:</h3> 
            <p>
                <a href="#">Blah</a>,
                <a href="#">Blah</a>,
                <a href="#">Blah</a>,
                <a href="#">Blah</a>
            </p>

        </div>
    </li>



    <li class="mega">
        <h2><a href="#">Blah</a></h2>
        <div>
            <h3>Blah</h3> 
            <p>

                <a href="#">Blah</a>,
                <a href="#">Blah</a>,
                <a href="#">Blah</a>,
                <a href="#">Blah</a>,
                <a href="#">Blah</a>,
                <a href="#">Blah</a>
            </p>
        </div>

    </li>


    <li>
        <h2><a href="#">Blah</a></h2>
    </li>

    <li class="mega">
        <h2><a href="#">Blah</a></h2>

        <div>
            <h3>Blah</h3> 
            <p>

                <a href="#">Blah</a>,


                <a href="#">Blah</a>

            </p>
            <h3>Miscellaneous</h3> 
            <p>

                <a href="#">Blah</a>

            </p>
        </div> 
    </li>

  </ul>

  <div class="colmask rightmenu">
    <div class="colleft">

      <div class="col1wrap">
        <div class="col1">


            <h1>Page Title</h1>



<table class="dataset">


</table>


        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col2">
        <!-- Column 2 start -->


<h2>More filters</h2>
<p>
<a href="#">Blah</a>
<a href="#">Blah</a>
<a href="#">Blah</a>

<a href="#">Blah</a>

</p>


<h2>Filter...</h2>








        <!-- Column 2 end -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div id="footer">
    <ul>

    </ul>
  </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

EDIT: yeah all the styles have to be in the same file, and that conditional is the best way to target it. I have that code in production and it works fairly well. I know it isn't ideal but it's better than anything else I can think of doing.

EDIT: I did HEAVY stripping of all of our business logic from this code. There are a lot of elements, styling, and javascript I stripped out. How it is supposed to work, is when you hover over the navigation elements, the gray dropdowns appear. For troubleshooting this problem, I removed the display: none; from those elements and now I am simply trying to get them to appear.

Comment: Please post your code on something like http://jsbin.com/ so we can debug it.

Comment: Btw: Your conditional comment using the body tag really isn't good style. Just include a css though a link tag in the conditional comment.

Comment: are you trying to get rid of the grey background in the boxes? What kind of functionality are you going after... hovering over the menu items shows the boxes... clicking shows them...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what I did, but the problem was fixed by the time I asked this question:

[Why does IE show the gray boxes below the content, instead of above?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3366670/why-does-ie-show-the-gray-boxes-below-the-content-instead-of-above)

The code is therein.